# ui-router navigating to parent

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, onsen-ui

i'm making an onsenui project, and I have a navigator, which has a back button, but I'm using the the UI-router from angular to handle my navigation.

so I have the following states:

```
$stateProvider
    .state("app", {
        abstract: true,
        templateUrl: "app/shared/Layout/Main.html",
        controller: "NavController"
    })
    .state("app.buildings", {
        url: "/buildings",
        onEnter: function ($rootScope, $stateParams, $timeout) {
            $timeout(function () {
                if (!$rootScope.mobile) {
                    $rootScope.navLand.resetToPage("app/components/BuildingList/BuildingListView.html");
                } else {
                    $rootScope.navPort.resetToPage("app/components/BuildingList/BuildingListView.html");
                }
            });
        }
        // templateUrl: "app/components/BuildingList/BuildingListView.html"
    })
    .state("app.buildings.details", {
        url: "/:buildingId",
        onEnter: function ($rootScope, $stateParams, $timeout) {
            $timeout(function () {
                if (!$rootScope.mobile) {
                    $rootScope.navLand.pushPage("app/components/BuildingDetail/BuildingDetailView.html");
                } else {
                    $rootScope.navPort.pushPage("app/components/BuildingDetail/BuildingDetailView.html");
                }
            }); 
        },
        onExit: function ($rootScope, $state) {
            $state.go("app.buildings");
            if ($rootScope.navLand) $rootScope.navLand.popPage();
            if ($rootScope.navPort) $rootScope.navPort.popPage();
        }
    })
    .state("app.buildingsDetails.Category", {
        url: "/buildings/:buildingId/category/:categoryId",
        // templateUrl: "app/components/BuildingDetail/BuildingDetailView.html"
    });
});
```

and in my views I tried doing:

```
<ons-toolbar>
    <div class="left">
        <ons-toolbar-button ng-click="menu.toggle()" ng-if="mobile">
            <ons-icon icon="ion-navicon" size="28px" fixed-width="false"></ons-icon>
        </ons-toolbar-button>
        <ons-toolbar-button class="toolbar-button--quiet" ui-sref="^">
            <ons-icon icon="ion-chevron-left" size="28px" fixed-width="false"></ons-icon>
            &nbsp;Back
        </ons-toolbar-button>
    </div>
    <div class="center"> {{vm.title}}</div>
</ons-toolbar>
```

as u can s    
        
            
                
            
            
                
                 Back
            
        
         {{vm.title}}

So i'm trying to use `ui-sref="^"` but this gives me the following error:

```
Error: Cannot transition to abstract state '^'
    at Object.transitionTo (scripts.js:3819)
    at Object.go (scripts.js:3744)
    at scripts.js:4857
    at angular.js:17855
    at completeOutstandingRequest (angular.js:5507)
    at angular.js:5784
```

So any clue on what I might be doing wrong?

**Update:** If I do `$state.go('^')` it works just fine

Comment: If you're currently in `app.building` state, then you'll get this error because its parent, the `app` state, is defined as abstract

Comment: I get the error when i'm in the `app.buildings.details` state

Comment: The error above mentioned comes only if you try to go to the abstract state. does that error come even if you directly provide templateURL or template ?

Comment: @murli2308 what do you mean? I'm in the `app.buildings.details` state and `^` should be `app.buildings` so this isn't an abstract state